# TFVC alternative to share feature

Tags: version-control, tfs, share

I'm looking for ideas as alternatives in TFVC to using the SourceGear Vault Share feature.  At the moment I have 2 sets of shared code libraries that I use for multiple solutions - an older (messier) set which compiles to .NET 3.5 and a newer cleaner set which compiles to .NET 4.  The 2 sets use different root namespaces but have a number of classes in common which I currently implement by sharing them in Vault.  I do want to keep the code in sync in both places - I don't want to branch or copy them.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have multiple projects/solutions (a .Net 3.5 solution/projects + .Net 4 solution/projects).  But use linked files to have the projects reference the same .cs files where appropriate.

When you choose Add Existing Item... click the dropdown next to the Add button to Add As Link:

[image]

Comment: I've just tried this (with Vault) and VS complains that the files are outside the binding root and won't be under source control.  I can't seem to get it to rejig the binding root on that project to allow it.  Not sure if this works differently for TFVC but I suspect it is a VS thing

Comment: You need to reconfigure your workspace mappings to include the files/folders in question.  You can do this from within VS ain the Workspace dialog.